# OpenMP improves performance on section but slowdown overall runtime

Tags: c++, openmp, slowdown

So I'm trying to improve the performance of my code. Its a physics simulator that perform several steps, one after another. One of that steps if computing the forces for each simulated point, and this can take a lot of time. For improving this, I'm using `pragma omp paralel for` for parallelizing the computations. This works fine and I see an improvement of 2x, from 6ms to 3ms.

Another step is to compute the change on the forces when a perturbation on the simulated positions is done, for which I do a perturbation and recompute the forces. I would expect this step to show some benefits, as computing the forces is now faster, but its showing a big slowdown which I dont understand.

I cant share the source code, but the pseucode would be something like this:

```
void Hessian::computeForcesPerturbation(Object &result)
{
    // m_fCurrent exists in the class
    perturbPosition(epsilon);
    fPerturb = computeForces;
    result = (fPerturb - m_fCurrent) / epsilon
}
```

I have no clue on what might be happening. I know that without proper code, its difficult to give a proper answer, but would be nice if someone has any clue of what might the problem or have faced something similar.

Here are the numbers with OpenMP

```
StretchEnergy: 2613
BendingEnergy: 2738
CG::applyHessians: 78792
```

and without OpenMP

```
StretchEnergy: 5867
BendingEnergy: 5874
CG::applyHessians: 69208
```

Edit:
Forces computations have some memory concurrency accesses, which I protec with a mutex. I do that by adding a std::mutex do the Node struct. That node struct contains the position, velocity and forces of the node, and now also the mutex. Could it be that adding the mutex changes the alignment in memory of the Node struct which affects performance in other parts (like perturbing the positions).

This are the Nodes structs

```
struct CoarseNode {
#ifdef DESIM_USE_OPENMP
    std::mutex mutex;
#endif
    deCore::Vector3 position;
    deCore::Vector3 velocity;
    deCore::Vector3 forces;
    std::uint32_t id;
};

struct Node {
#ifdef USE_OPENMP
    std::mutex mutex;
#endif
    deCore::Vector3 displacement;
    deCore::Vector3 displacementVelocity;
    deCore::Vector3 forces;

    deCore::Real eCoordinate;

    deCore::Real barycentricCoordinates[3];
    std::uint32_t coarseNodeIds[3];
    std::uint32_t id;
};
```

and some functions that compute the positions from the `Node` data

```
deCore::Vector4 deSim::HybridFabric::SimulationNode::position(const Node &hybridYarnNode,
                                                              const SimulationNode::CoarseNode *coarseNodes)
{
    deCore::Vector4 d;
    d.head<3>() = coarseNodes[hybridYarnNode.coarseNodeIds[0]].position * hybridYarnNode.barycentricCoordinates[0] +
                  coarseNodes[hybridYarnNode.coarseNodeIds[1]].position * hybridYarnNode.barycentricCoordinates[1] +
                  coarseNodes[hybridYarnNode.coarseNodeIds[2]].position * hybridYarnNode.barycentricCoordinates[2] +
                  hybridYarnNode.state.head<3>();

    d(3) = hybridYarnNode.eCoordinate;
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Is there any concurrent memory access or lock? Are you compiling with optimization?

Comment: Yes, there are concurrent memory accesses which are protected with a mutex (it gave me better performance than using openmp primitives), but this concurrency happens during the forces computation, the rest of the code is untouched. Already checked that the result is the same.
Optimizations are on.

Comment: Question edited with some more information